# How find documents with latitude and longitude and a minimum distance in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, latitude-longitude

Here's the example of a document stored in mongodb:

```
_id: ObjectId("5da7b7c97c1b89790cea1f78")
lat: "11.927677"
lng: "121.949457"
formatted_address: "Caticlan Jetty Port 2 & Passenger Terminal, 502, Caticlan, Malay, Akla..."
geocoder: "barikoi"
unix: 1571272649092
```

I want to find the documents that are within a minimum distance from a given latitude longitude.

Currently, I'm retrieving all the documents and\ looping over the records using the `for` loop and calculating distance in every iteration, and storing the result in another array if the calculated distance less than the minimum distance. Finally returning the result array.

I'm using the `geolib` npm package to calculate the distances.

Here's the code:

```
database
        .collection(collection_name)
        .find({})
        .sort({ _id: -1 })
        .toArray((err, docs) => {
                const results = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                    let {
                        _id,
                        lat: stored_lat,
                        lng: stored_lng,
                        formatted_address,
                        geocoder,
                    } = docs[i];

                    let distance = geolib.getDistance(
                        { latitude: lat, longitude: lng },
                        { latitude: stored_lat, longitude: stored_lng }
                    );

                    if (isNaN(distance)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (distance < minimum_distance) {
                        results.push({
                            _id,
                            geocoder,
                            formatted_address,
                            lat,
                            lng,
                            address,
                            stored_lat,
                            stored_lng,
                            distance,
                        });
                    }
                }

                cb(null, results);
                return;
            }
        });
```

I hope there's a better approach to achieve this.

Comment: @Minsky, I want to find the documents that are within a minimum distance from a given latitude longitude. Updated the question.

Comment: Try `db.collection.aggregate([   {$sort:{_id:-1}}, {     $addFields: {       coord: [{$convert:{input:"$lat", to:"double"}}, {$convert:{input:"$lng", to:"double"}}]     }   },   {$match:{    coord: {       $geoWithin: { $center: [ [ refLat, refLong ] , maxDist] }    }   }   } ])` Think u need to change db.coll.aggregate to something similar

Comment: I had to convert the lat long of $center array from string to double, and I've used $centerSphere instead of $center. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't realize that. It would be faster if you had a field like `coord:[lng,lat]` and covered by an index. Of course, if you're not communicating with an application it's fine.